# Android - Try Catch is not catching the exception and it's not displaying my toast message

Tags: java, android, exception, try-catch

I'm new to Android programming and taking a Coursera class. In my assignment app, I'm trying to catch any exceptions when the user does not enter or enters incorrect time information (HH:MM:SS).

My app crashes right after user error instead of displaying my Toast message or displaying a Log message to Logcat.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
try {
    Date dt = formatter.parse(MileTime);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(dt);
    int hours = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minutes = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int seconds = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    int duration = 3600 * hours + 60 * minutes + seconds;
    int steps_per_second = 3;

    int running_rate = duration * steps_per_second;

    //pleaseStop = false; //DouglasZare example, don't need this.
    mHandler = new Handler(); // .os package class when importing
    mLeftfoot = findViewById(R.id.leftfoot);
    mRightfoot = findViewById(R.id.rightfoot);     
    mFootAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.foot); //this looks to the foot.xml file for the animations
    stepRecursive();       
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e(TAG, "Invalid Mile Time Entry", e);
    Toast.makeText(Assignment3MainActivity_V3_DouglasZare_AnimationCancel.this,
    "Please Enter Valid Time Stamp HH:MM:SS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

The error log is here: http://pastebin.com/By7FWxLk.

This error makes perfect sense and is intentional.

```
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
```

What do I fix to get my catch statement to prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

Fixed. Ugh. I changed ParseException to just Exception. It doesn't make any sense to me...The Exception I want to catch IS ParseException.

```
catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, "Invalid Mile Time Entry", e);
        Toast.makeText(Assignment3MainActivity_V3_DouglasZare_AnimationCancel.this,
                "Please Enter Valid Time Stamp HH:MM:SS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: That means the exception thrown is not ParseException. Check the exception type in your logs and change the code accordingly

Comment: It is actually best practice to catch each individual exception - so first attempt to catch `ParseException`, then attempt to catch the `IllegalStateException`. If you want to disregard *best practice*, then you should catch on `Throwable`, the parent class to all `Exceptions`.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I will try to catch each individual exception with | in between each exception.

Comment: @StacyM: +1 for not accepting your own answer and looking for the correct solution instead of fix :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the exception being thrown is `IllegalStateException` not `ParseException`.

If you look at line 5 of your crash log, you'll see the exception that gets passed up to you is an `IllegalStateException`. This is because the ParseException is caught and then an `IllegalStateException` is re-thrown afterwards.

Here's an example of multiple catch blocks.

```
try {
    //some code that can throw an exception
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    //catch the IllegalStateExeption
} catch (Exception e) {
   //catch all the ones I didn't think of.
}
```

Comment: So, does order matter? I figured that my ParseException would still catch because one of the exceptions was ParseException. Should I always use "Exception" to be safe?

Comment: It's not so much about order. The parse exception never made it up to your code because it was caught lower down. Having a generic catch is a good solution but it's not the best. You can have multiple catch statements to handle all the expected exception types and then have a generic Exception catch at the end to handle anything unexpected.